# Cannot run cquery

Tags: package, use-package

I have been using `rtags` as my primary C++ mode, but I found that it's performance is not satisfying for large code bases e.g. Linux kernel.

It takes more than 5 seconds to find definitions. This it not *so* bad, but I heard that `cquery` provides better performance.

So I installed cquery and set up my `.el` file:

```
(use-package lsp-mode)

(use-package lsp-ui :commands lsp-ui-mode)
(use-package company-lsp :commands company-lsp)

(use-package cquery
  :config
  (setq cquery-executable "/path/to/cquery"))
```

I followed the steps introduced in the documentation, namely:

1. Prepare `compile_commands.json` (I used `bear`)
2. Open file
3. Run lsp by `M-x lsp`

At this point, I get error message, saying:

> error in process filter: Symbol’s value as variable is void: method

and the status bar halts at `LSP[cquery:18565 status:starting]`

Am I missing any steps?

Comment: Try enabling traceback though `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` and post the results. The error message implies that you don't have variable named `method`.  I think, it comes from `eioei` package, but I could be wrong. I'd need to see the actual source to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a bug in `dash 2.14.1`, where the `&hash` statement in `-let` bindings is broken.

Update to `dash 2.15.0` for a fix.